# Can i have both cygwin and mingw in my computer,

Tags: c++, windows

I am having windows64x operating system, by installing both mingw and cygwin in same computer, will it make any conflicts between these compilers??

Comment: If they're on distinct paths I don't see a problem. Just make sure to call them with the explicit path or give different names to the executables, which will be a pain.

Comment: Consider this post on superuser -> https://superuser.com/questions/820989/installing-cygwin-with-mingw-in-windows

Comment: This should definitely be on [su]. This isn't strictly for programming. Heck, I'd even answer it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it. I have them both installed on my windows machine. `Cygwin` @

> C:\cygwin64

and `MinGW` @

> c:\MinGW\

I use Cygwin to execute bash scripts from within the command console and mingw/msyst as a build toolchain for several projects.